# jQuery's 'click' function when user highlights text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery's `click` function to check the formatting of highlighted text, however the function isn't always called.

If you highlight part of a line it will work as expected, however if you highlight the entire line it simple doesn't call at all.

Here is a JSFiddle for you to try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/ZMYRH/

Is there any chance I'm using this function incorrectly? Or is there a workaround to what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because a `click` event is only fired if the `mousedown` and `mouseup` event occur on the *same* element.

In your case the `mouseup` event would be more appropriate as it will allow the user to drag a selection across elements.

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMYRH/1/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to have solved the problem, I'm getting the same results. Are you sure you didn't carefully select from the text still instead of the whitespace?

Comment: When selecting from the grey box (i've added in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZMYRH/2/) all the way to the end of the line, it doesn't respond.